# Найти в тексте телефонные номера и заменить последние цифры на определённые символы

Tags: python, регулярные-выражения

Программа должна найти в тексте телефонные номера и скрыть последние X цифр (количество цифр, которые нужно скрыть, а также символ которым будут скрыты цифры должен выбрать и ввести сам пользователь с клавиатуры). Предполагается, что номера телефонов при вводе уже нормализованы и отформатированы таким образом:

● код начинается с символа "+" и содержит от одной до трёх цифр

● номер содержит 9 цифр в 3 группах, по 3 цифры в каждой, разделенных пробелами

Примеры

Ввод: 
text= [+32 471 229 313]  mask char=X Digits to hide=3

Вывод: +32 471 229 ХХХ

Ввод: 
text= [Sample +132 324 368 546 text] mask char=$ Digits to hide=4

Вывод: Sample +132 324 36$ $$$ text

Ввод: 
text=[Sample +48 845 546 546, +48 777 777 777 text 898 845 566 Sample text]   mask char=% digits to hide=2

Вывод: Sample +48 845 546 5%%, +48 777 777 7%% text 898 845 566 Sample text

Comment: Использование регулярного выражения - обязательное условие?

Comment: А вопрос-то в чём? Или вы просто хотите, чтобы решение написали за вас?

Comment: @nomnoms12 ну, вдруг человек только знакомится с этим и не знает про регулярные выражения?

Comment: @Huskey У человека стоит метка "регулярные-выражения". Поэтому я и уточняю.

Comment: @nomnoms12 виноват, не увидел

Comment: Использование регулярного выражения - не обязательное условие, но мне показалось что с их помощью будет легче всего справиться с заданием.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

***Код:***

```py
import re


string = input('Текст: ')
symbol = input('Символ: ')
count = int(input('Количество: '))

pattern = '[\\d%s](?=(?:[\\d%s]{3})+(?![\\d%s]))' % (symbol, symbol, symbol)

nums = re.findall(r'\+\d{1,3} \d{3} \d{3} \d{3}', string)
for num in nums:
    raw_num = num.replace(' ', '')[1:-count] + symbol * count
    new_num = '+' + re.sub(pattern, r'\g<0> ', raw_num)

    string = string.replace(num, new_num)

print(string)
```

***Пояснения:***

Используя регулярное выражение `\+\d{1,3} \d{3} \d{3} \d{3}`, я нахожу все номера в строке.

Затем я преобразовываю их в вид `+123456789012` и заменяю символы.

Перед этим я генерирую регулярное выражение для разбивки номера в изначальный вид.
К примеру, если символ `#`, то регулярное выражение будет выглядеть так:
`[\d#](?=(?:[\d#]{3})+(?![\d#]))`.

Наконец, заменяю номер в исходной строке.

**P. S.:**
Мне не очень нравится собственный код. Кажется, это можно сделать очевиднее. Буду рад любым Вашим комментариям и замечаниям.